# PIL rotate image colors (BGR -> RGB)

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I have an image where the colors are BGR. How can I transform my PIL image to swap the B and R elements of each pixel in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming no alpha band, isn't it as simple as this?

```
b, g, r = im.split()
im = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
```

Edit:

Hmm...  It seems PIL has a few bugs in this regard... `im.split()` doesn't seem to work with recent versions of PIL (1.1.7). It may (?) still work with 1.1.6, though...

Comment: the solution was to load the image properly in the first place =P but this seems lovely

Comment: `np.roll` will convert BGR to RBG, not RGB. If you want to do this in numpy, you can use `data[...,[2,1,0]]` to swap the channels. But if you're already using OpenCV or PIL, just go with Martin Beckett's response.

Comment: Another numpy alternative to @LukeYeager's suggestion: `np.flip(image_bgr, axis=2)`

Answer (score 154):

I know it is an old question, but I had the same problem. I solved it using the following code:

```
img = img[:, :, ::-1]
```

Comment: The data has 3 dimensions: width, height, and color. `::-1` effectively reverses the order of the colors. The width and height are not affected.

Comment: Good, I got it following your note and my testing.`::-1` is actually a shorthand of numpy operation `[start:end:step]`, and `start`/`end` is decided automatically.

Comment: for clarity, 
img = img[:, :, : :-1] is equivalent to img = img[:, :, [2,1,0]].
I think the later is better as it is more explicit.

Comment: img[:, :, : :-1] is not equivalent to img[:, :, [2,1,0]]. The former utilizes basic index and the latter uses advanced indexing. The latter will make a copy of your image while the former does not.

Comment: This is also significantly more performant than the cv2.cvtColor function suggested in an answer above.

Answer (score 113):

Just to add a more up to date answer:

With the new cv2 interface images loaded are now numpy arrays automatically.
But openCV cv2.imread() loads images as BGR while numpy.imread() loads them as RGB.

The easiest way to convert is to use openCV cvtColor.

```
import cv2
srcBGR = cv2.imread("sample.png")
destRGB = cv2.cvtColor(srcBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Pretty much the only reason you would have a BGR image is if you're using OpenCV. Your solution is the right thing to do. The other top answer is functional, but would be slow in processing large images.

Comment: Why is this not on top ?

Comment: Because the simplest solution is literally just: img = img[..., ::-1]

Comment: Does cv2 guarantee that images are contiguous? OpencCV (at least in c++) will start each new row on a 4byte boundary  so you have to be careful moving raw bytes around

Comment: thanks for this...i am using them in the same codes,got me crazy for a while@RyanSoklaski that is actually more confusing without knowing which is default for opencv or PIL but very neat

Answer (score 16):

Adding a solution using the ellipsis

`image = image[...,::-1]`

In this case, the ellipsis `...` is equivalent to `:,:` while `::-1` inverts the order of the last dimension (channels).

Answer (score 10):

This was my best answer.  This does, by the way, work with Alpha too.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys 

sub = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
sub = sub.convert("RGBA")
data = np.array(sub) 
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T 
data = np.array([blue, green, red, alpha])
data = data.transpose()
sub = Image.fromarray(data)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick footnote for anyone writing code that might have to deal with 4-channel images, and discovering that the simple numpy answer seems to be eating their alpha channel.

```
np_image[:,:,[0,1,2]] = np_image[:,:,[2,1,0]]
```

will preserve the alpha data if there is a fourth channel, whereas

```
np_image = np_image[:,:,[2,1,0]]
```

will overwrite the 4-channel image with only reversed 3-channel data. (And the even simpler numpy answer, img = img[:,:,::-1], will give you ARGB data, which would be bad, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
import cv2
srcBGR = cv2.imread("sample.png")
destRGB = cv2.cvtColor(srcBGR,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Just to clarify Martin Beckets solution, as I am unable to comment. 
You need cv2. in front of the color constant.

Comment: Ah useful, thanks. Note you can suggest an edit and you get +2 rep if it gets approved

Comment: thanks, Claudiu, I'll try that:
"""Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"""
Well - that did not go so well ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Application of other solutions. Just for a temporary measure.

```py
import numpy

im = Image.fromarray(numpy.array(im)[:,:,::-1])
```

Comment: This is how I do it usually, Although if its got alpha `Image.fromarray(np.array(img)[:,:,:3][:,:,::-1])`

Comment: You can apply slicing directly on im variable since this is an array and there is no need to call numpy again.

Answer (score 3):

```
im = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (width, height), bgr_buf, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 0)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Because obviously you need to use `np.shape` or someting like that to get the dimension. Also what is `bgr_buf`?

Answer (score 2):

Using the ideas explained before... using numpy you could.

```
bgr_image_array = numpy.asarray(bgr_image)
B, G, R = bgr_image_array.T
rgb_image_array = np.array((R, G, B)).T
rgb_image = Image.fromarray(rgb_image_array, mode='RGB')
```

Additionally it can remove the Alpha channel.

```
assert bgra_image_array.shape == (image_height, image_width, 4)
B, G, R, _ = bgra_image_array.T
rgb_image_array = np.array((R, G, B)).T
```

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: Use `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))` if you already import `cv2`.

---

Speed comparison:

```
%%timeit
img_ = Image.fromarray(img[...,::-1])
# 5.77 ms ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
img_ = Image.fromarray(img[...,[2,1,0]])
# 6.2 ms ± 2.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
img_ = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
# 442 µs ± 4.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Problem is, OP ask if `img` is already in `PIL` image format, whereas `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))` require `img` in `numpy` array format.

But, `cv2.imread()` is most likely the reason you got BGR image. Not `Image.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an alpha band, use this:

```
img = img[:,:, [2, 1, 0, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the [`ImageMath`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagemath.htm) module.

#### Edit:

Joe's solution is even better, I was overthinking it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Flip channels the way you want!

```
# You source order
source = 'BGR'

# The order you want
target = 'RGB'

# Grab the indices of channel in last dimension
image = image[...,[target.index(s) for s in source]]
```