# PIL fromarray function is giving wierd colormap

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am writing a little gui for testing opencv functions - to easily change parameter values  (for thresholding, blob detection etc.).  I started writing the gui using tkinter and get wierd result with the Image.fromarray function - my image gets a blue tint; when I display with cv2.imshow there's no such tint so its gotta be an artifact of fromarry, I blv.  I  checked the mode and its RGB as expected. The image pairs are before and after blob detection (which draws little circles).  The left pair is opencv and the right pair is in my tkinter gui.

```
        tk_img=Image.fromarray(newImg) 
        tk_photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(tk_img)
        mod=tk_img.mode
        print('mode:'+str(mod))
        label1 = Tkinter.Label(self, image=tk_photo)
        label1.image = tk_photo
        label1.grid(row = Imrow, column = Im2col, columnspan = Im2col, sticky=Tkinter.NW)
        self.update()

        cv2.imshow('orig', currentImg)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.imshow('current', newImg)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: openCV windows on left, my gui on right - why is right pic blue???]

Comment: So i did a kludgy workaround of saving the image to a temp file and reading :                                                           r=cv2.imwrite('temp.jpg',img)
tk_img = Image.open('temp.jpg')tk_photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(tk_img)

Comment: I would see if pillow does the same or if this has been fixed in a patch.  (Pillow also runs on 3.x.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV works with images using BGR color order. You need to change color order.

```
newImg = newImg[...,[2,1,0]]
```

Look this tread for more info [PIL rotate image colors (BGR -> RGB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661557/pil-rotate-image-colors-bgr-rgb)