# How to change the RGB to BGR in python PIL IMAGE?P

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library

I have an image where the colors are based on RGB . How could I use PIL image library to change RGB to BGR.

Yes, it is very similar to [PIL rotate image colors (BGR -> RGB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661557/pil-rotate-image-colors-bgr-rgb) but working in the opposite, my purpose is to change RGB to BGR whereas the similar question is about changing BGR to RGB.

```
b, g, r = im.split()
im = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
```

seems to be a simpler solution, but split() doesn't support to latest PIL anymore.

What I like to know more is how to reverse this underlying code from RGB to BGR

```
data = np.asarray(im)
im = Image.fromarray(np.roll(data, 1, axis=-1))
```

---------------------------------------update -------------------------

```
pil_im_obj = Image.open(path)
print pil_im_obj
# output <PIL.JpegImagePlugin image mode= RGB size=591*500>
data = np.asarray(pil_im_obj)
pil_im = Image.fromarray(np.roll(data,1,axis=-1))
print pil_im

#output  : <PIL.Image.Image image mode = RGB size= 591*500>
```

I tried the conversion as mentioned in the comments, but still output shows after the conversion, it is still RGB image

Comment: Swapping RGB and BGR is a symmetric operation, the same code works for both conversions.

Comment: sorry,@MarkRansom, I have updated with a simple test, it doesn't seem to change from RGB to BGR

Comment: It's going to *say* it's RGB, but the channels will actually be BGR. You just have to ignore the discrepancy.