# how to convert a 1-dimensional image array to PIL image in Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

My question is related to a [Kaggle data science competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data). I'm trying to read an image from a one-dimensional array containing **1-bit grayscale** pixel information (**0 to 255)** for an **28x28 image**. So the array is from **0 to 783** where each pixel is encoded as x = i * 28 + j.

Converted into a two-dimensional 28x28 matrix this:

```
000 001 002 003 ... 026 027
028 029 030 031 ... 054 055
056 057 058 059 ... 082 083
 |   |   |   |  ...  |   |
728 729 730 731 ... 754 755
756 757 758 759 ... 782 783
```

For reasons of image manipulation (resizing, skewing) I would like to read that array into an in-memory PIL image. I did some research on the [Matplotlib image function](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html), which I think is most promising. Another idea is the [Numpy image functions](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html#numpy).

**What I'm looking for**, is a code example that shows me how to load that 1-dimensional array via Numpy or Matplotlib or anything else. Or how to convert that array into a 2-dimensional image using for instance Numpy.vstack and then read it as an image.

Comment: Simple use `np.reshape()` with the desired shape of `(28,28)` with it?

Comment: and how to use it to load the image? code?

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure about reading image part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a NumPy array to PIL image using `Image.fromarray`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

arr = np.random.randint(255, size=(28*28))
img = Image.fromarray(arr.reshape(28,28), 'L')
```

`L` mode indicates the array values represent luminance. The result will be a gray-scale image.

Comment: just found [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html#sklearn.datasets.load_digits) too, which is used for the [Kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/EnteringSubmission).

Comment: How do I do the same with color image stored as `ndarray`, where we have 3 channels BGR? @unutbu

Comment: @Santhosh: To convert BGR --> RGB you could use [`img = img[..., ::-1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661557/pil-rotate-image-colors-bgr-rgb#comment76959337_9641163).

Comment: Thank You @unutbu `img = img[...,::-1]` seems to be much faster than `color conversion` in `OpenCV` in which I'm working. Even this worked `out = Image.fromarray(ima.reshape(ima.shape[0],ima.shape[1],3),"RGB")`

Comment: Your posts have helped me a lot! Would love to learn much more tricks from you  @unutbu