# how to convert flattened array of RGB image(1-D) back to original image

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

I have flattened 1D array of (1*3072) created from RGB image of dimension(32*32*3). I want to extract back the original RGB image of dimension(32*32*3) and plot it.

I have tried the solution suggested in [how to convert a 1-dimensional image array to PIL image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952853/how-to-convert-a-1-dimensional-image-array-to-pil-image-in-python)

But it's not working for me, As it seems it is for a greyscale image

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import array
img = Image.open("sampleImage.jpg")
arr = array(img)
arr = arr.flatten()
print(arr.shape)
#tried with 'L' & 'RGB' both
img2 = Image.fromarray(arr.reshape(200,300), 'RGB') 

plt.imshow(img2, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

"Getting below error which expected because it is not able covert RGB"

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 180000 into shape (200,300)
```

Comment: `reshape(200, 300, 3)` because it's a 3 channel image. Your image is 200x300 (which is 60k pixels), and each pixel has 3 color values (RGB) so there's actually 180k values. But if you try to reshape into a 200x300 array, that's only 60k values, so nowhere to put the other 120k values, so it gives you a `ValueError`.

Comment: related [np.unravel_index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked after changing reshape(200, 300, 3) with/without 'RGB'  but it was failing earlier with (reshape(200, 300, 3),  'L').                                           
 ``` img2 = Image.fromarray(arr.reshape(200,300,3)) ```

Comment: Regarding dimension, I was trying a sample image of Dim 200*300*3. My actual dataset has the image of Dim 32*32*3. Was facing issue on both. Anyway, it is solved now.

Answer (score 2):

In order to interpret an array as an RGB image, it needs to have 3 channels.  A channel is the 3rd dimension in the numpy array. So change your code to this:

`img2 = Image.fromarray(arr.reshape(200,300,3), 'RGB')`

I should mention that you talk about your flattened array being 1x3072, yet the example code seems to assume 200x300x3, which would be 1x180,000 when flattened.  Which of these two is the truth, I couldn't tell you.