# How to use PIL to create images from the row values in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

Here is [my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw2p9155zgmkkl5/df22.csv?dl=1).

It's a csv file with 36 columns. **I intend to convert each row into a picture and store it as a database that can be fed to a neural network.**

I have seen and tried converting 1d numpy arrays to pictures using `PIL`, but have no idea how to implement it on the entire data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

dataframe = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw2p9155zgmkkl5/df22.csv?dl=1',index_col=0)
dataframe
```

I have created a [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ovMyn4-qvGWQCgmWL710t2wm5ile1nyD?usp=sharing) to make it easier to try.

### Data

- First 10 rows

```py
HOME,WORK,SHOP,FREETIME,ACCOMPANY,FOOD,OTHER,AM,PM,MIDDAY,NIGHT,firsttrip_time,lasttrip_time,home_traveltime,work_traveltime,shop_traveltime,freetime_traveltime,accompany_traveltime,food_traveltime,home_traveldistance,work_traveldistance,shop_traveldistance,freetime_traveldistance,accompany_traveldistance,food_traveldistance,TRPMILES_mean,TRVL_MIN_mean,home_dweltime,work_dweltime,shop_dweltime,freetime_dweltime,accompany_dweltime,food_dweltime,AVG_VEH_CNT,TRPMILES_sum,TRVL_MIN_sum
2.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,9.0,20.0,32.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.72,0.0,0.0,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.58,25.4,115.0,0.0,0.0,118.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,84.22,127.0
2.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,5.0,2.0,0.0,9.0,20.0,32.5,0.0,0.0,10.0,2.5,0.0,0.72,0.0,0.0,0.26,0.01,0.0,0.37,16.88,115.0,0.0,0.0,51.67,12.5,0.0,1.0,85.22,135.0
2.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,9.0,20.0,11.5,8.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.19,0.12,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.14,9.4,46.0,243.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,21.0,47.0
1.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,0.0,13.0,16.0,20.0,0.0,17.5,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.17,0.0,0.07,0.0,0.0,0.03,0.09,16.25,0.0,0.0,50.0,0.0,0.0,20.0,1.0,10.0,65.0
1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,13.0,20.0,30.0,0.0,0.0,35.0,0.0,0.0,0.41,0.0,0.0,0.41,0.0,0.0,0.41,32.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,385.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,24.0,65.0
1.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,11.0,14.0,30.0,0.0,12.5,0.0,0.0,10.0,0.31,0.0,0.15,0.0,0.0,0.02,0.16,16.25,0.0,0.0,25.0,0.0,0.0,80.0,0.0,18.22,65.0
2.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,0.0,10.0,17.0,3.0,0.0,12.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.01,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.01,8.17,1.0,0.0,107.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.5,1.0,49.0
1.0,8.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.0,6.0,0.0,0.0,7.0,15.0,30.0,26.0,30.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.52,0.52,0.48,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.51,27.14,0.0,6.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.5,104.0,190.0
3.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,7.0,0.0,0.0,9.0,15.0,7.67,0.0,3.0,10.0,0.0,3.5,0.11,0.0,0.02,0.01,0.0,0.09,0.08,6.0,50.33,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,32.0,1.5,18.61,48.0
3.0,0.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,4.0,0.0,0.0,8.0,14.0,8.0,0.0,8.67,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.09,0.0,0.09,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.09,8.33,43.33,0.0,47.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.5,15.11,50.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [how to convert a 1-dimensional image array to PIL image in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952853/how-to-convert-a-1-dimensional-image-array-to-pil-image-in-python) applied to a dataframe
- The images are for each row.

  - Since an image is rectangular, we can make a square that is `6 x 6`, because the rows are of length 36.
  - This will 214217 very tiny images, therefore they can be resized to the required size by using `.resize`

    - Resizing all the images will take a few minutes, depending on the size.
- Use `.apply` with `axis=1` to apply the function to each row of data in the dataframe.

  - `.values` will extract the row values `x` into a numpy array of shape `(36,)`, which can be reshaped, with `.reshape`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 

# create the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/sw2p9155zgmkkl5/df22.csv?dl=1', index_col=0)

# create images
images = df.apply(lambda x: Image.fromarray(x.values.reshape(6, 6), 'L').resize((200, 200)), axis=1)

# show image 0
images[0]
```

- The following image, represents the data from the first row of `df`

```py
df.iloc[0, :].values.reshape(6, 6)

array([[2.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
       [2.000e+00, 1.000e+00, 2.000e+00, 2.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 9.000e+00],
       [2.000e+01, 3.250e+01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
       [0.000e+00, 7.200e-01, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.000e-02, 0.000e+00],
       [0.000e+00, 5.800e-01, 2.540e+01, 1.150e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
       [1.180e+02, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 1.000e+00, 8.422e+01, 1.270e+02]])
```

[image]

- The white border is just from cutting and pasting, it's not part of the image.