# Convert UIImage from BGR to RGB

Tags: python, swift, opencv, numpy, base64

As the title suggests, I'm having some trouble with some UIImage color space conversions. The TL;DR version is that I need a way to convert a UIIMage in BGR format to RGB.

Here's the flow of events in my app:

1. App: get Image
2. App: convert to base64 and send to server
3. Server: convert base64 to an Image to use
4. Server: convert Image back to base64 String
5. Server: send base64 string to app
6. App: convert base64 string to UIImage

[RGB version of the Test-Image on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwsp1.png)

[BGR version of the Test-Image client-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4cbp.png)

It's at this point that the UIImage displayed is in BGR format. My best guess is that something goes wrong at step 4, because up until then the image is in RGB format (I've written it to a file and checked). I've added the code to step 4 below just for reference. I'm actively looking to change the color space of the UIImage client-side, but I'm not opposed to fixing the issue server-side. Either solution would work.

Step 2: Convert UIIMage to base64 string

```
  let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(map.image,0.95)!
  let base64EnCodedStr: String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Step 3: Convert base64 String to a PIL Image

```
import io
import cv2
import base64 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Take in base64 string and return PIL image
def stringToImage(base64_string):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
```

Step 4: Convert Image (numpy array) back to a base64 string

```
# Convert a numpyArray into a base64 string in JPEG format
def imageToString(npArray):

    # convert array to PIL Image
    newImage = Image.fromarray(npArray.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')

    # convert to JPEG format
    file = io.BytesIO()
    newImage.save(file, format="JPEG")

    # reset file pointer to start
    file.seek(0)
    img_bytes = file.read()

    # encode data
    encodedData = base64.b64encode(img_bytes)

    return encodedData.decode('ascii')
```

## EDIT:

As was mentioned earlier, there were two locations where I could do the conversions: Sever-side or client-side. Thanks to the responses to this question I was able to find solutions for both scenarios.

### Solution 1: Server-side

referring to the code in step 4, change the first line in that function to the following:

```
 # convert array to PIL Image
 newImage = Image.fromarray( npArray[...,[2,1,0]] ) # swap color channels which converts BGR -> RGB
```

### Solution 2: Client-side

Refer to @dfd 's solution. It's well written and works wonderfully. Here's the slightly adapted version I've tested in my application (which uses swift 4).

```
let data =  NSData(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)

let uiInput = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
let ciInput = CIImage(image: uiInput!)
let ctx = CIContext(options: nil)
let swapKernel = CIColorKernel( string:
    "kernel vec4 swapRedAndGreenAmount(__sample s) {" +
                 "return s.bgra;" +
     "}"
)
let ciOutput = swapKernel?.apply(withExtent: (ciInput?.extent)!, arguments: [ciInput as Any])
let cgImage = ctx.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciInput?.extent)!)
let rgbOutput = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are starting with RGB, sending it up to the server to do some things, and when it comes back to the client it's BGR? And you're wondering how to convert it back to BGR once it returns to the client?

Comment: @Paolo: Yes, except for that last sentence. It comes back in BGR format and I want to convert it back to RGB format.

Comment: Can you show how you're converting the image to base64 and then back to an image? Basically steps 2 and 3. It's very odd that you're getting a reversed order. A quick fix to reverse the order on the server might be to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4661557/887210

Comment: @ColGraff: I've updated my question to include the code for steps 2 & 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a very simple CIKernel to swap things:

```
kernel vec4 swapRedAndGreenAmount(__sample s) {
    return s.bgra;
}
```

Here's the Swift code to use it:

```
let uiInput = UIImage(named: "myImage")
let ciInput = CIImage(image: uiInput!)
let ctx = CIContext(options: nil)
let swapKernel = CIColorKernel( source:
    "kernel vec4 swapRedAndGreenAmount(__sample s) {" +
        "return s.bgra;" +
    "}"
)
let ciOutput = swapKernel?.apply(extent: (ciInput?.extent)!, arguments: [ciInput as Any])
let cgImage = ctx.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciInput?.extent)!)
let uiOutput = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
```

Be aware of a few things:

- This will work on devices running **iOS 9 or later**.
- Second and almost as important, this uses CoreImage and the GPU. Thus, testing this on a simulator may take seconds to render. But on a device it will take microseconds.
- I tend to use a `CIContext` to create a `CGImage` before ending up with a `UIImage`. You *may* be able to remove this step and go straight from a `CIImage` to a `UIImage`.
- Excuse the wrapping/unwrapping, it's converted from old code. You can probably do a better job.

**Explanation:**

Using CoreImage "Kernel" code, which until iOS 11 could only be a subset of GLSL code, I wrote a simple `CIColorKernel` that takes a pixel's RGB value and returns the pixel color as GRB.

A `CIColorKernel` is optimized to work on a single pixel at a time with *no* access to the pixels surrounding it. Unlike that, a `CIWarpKernel` is optimized to "warp" a pixel based on the pixels around it. Both of these are (more or less) optimized subclasses of a `CIKernel`, which - until iOS 11 and Metal Performance Shaders - is about the closest you get to using `openGL` inside of `CoreImage`.

**Final edit:**

What this solution does is **swap** a pixel's RGB one-by-one using CoreImage. It's fast because it uses the GPU, deceptively fast (because the simulator does not give you anything close to real-time performance on a device), and simple (because it swaps things from RGB to BGR).

The actual code to do this is straightforward. Hopefully it works as a start for those who want to do much larger "under the hood" things using CoreImage.

**EDIT (25 February 2021):**

As of WWDC 2019 Apple deprecated openGL - specifically `GLKit` - in favor of `MetalKit`. For a color kernel like this, it's rather trivial to convert this code. Warp kernels are slightly more trickier though.

As for *when* Apple will "kill" OpenGL is hard to say. We all know that someday `UIKit` will also be deprecated, but (showing my age now) it may not be in my lifetime. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, unfortunately this didn't solve my problem, It just turned the background pink. I feel like this is an important detail, but I don't know what to make of it. I've uploaded the results using your code  [Here](http://imgur.com/9Ar7kpX).

Comment: @NathanOrtega it looks like he swapped red and green, try swapping red and blue instead, i.e. `return s.bgra;` instead of `return s.grba;`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It was *my* code that wanted that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Paolo: Thanks! that was it! And @dfd: I'll accept your answer as soon as you finish that edit.

Comment: @dfd: your edit was close, but wasn't what I used to solve my problem, just change `return s.gbra;` to `return s.bgra;` in your answer.

Comment: Done. I've always felt I was somewhat dyslexic - now I know! Anyways, I'm glad I help you with your issue.

Comment: Caution with this one - it works, however it's deprecated and causing memory leaks.

Comment: @AppDevGuy, I'll add a note about the depreciation. In my defense note that Apple deprecated OpenGL (I'm assuming that's what you are referring to) almost 2 years after my answer. As for the memory leak? I have none in my usage, but maybe it's *how* it's being implemented. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No probs and agreed - I should have included in my comment how I am using it which led to the discovery of memory leaks - `CIContext` is not clearing the cache so there's a build  up of memory in my specific use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do it using `CoreImage` or `CoreGraphics` since iOS does not give you much leeway with regards to creating custom colorspaces. However, I found something that may help using OpenCV from this article: https://sriraghu.com/2017/06/04/computer-vision-in-ios-swiftopencv/. It requires a bit of Objective-C but with a bridging header, the code will be hidden away once it's written.

> - Add a new file -> ‘Cocoa Touch Class’, name it ‘OpenCVWrapper’ and set
>     language to Objective-C. Click Next and select Create. When it
>     prompted to create bridging header click on the ‘Create Bridging
>     Header’ button. Now you can observe that there are 3 files created
>     with names: OpenCVWrapper.h, OpenCVWrapper.m, and -Bridging-Header.h.
>     Open ‘-Bridging-Header.h’ and add the following line: #import
>     “OpenCVWrapper.h”
> - Go to ‘OpenCVWrapper.h’ file and add the following
>     lines of code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OpenCVWrapper: NSObject

+ (UIImage *) rgbImageFromBGRImage: (UIImage *) image;

@end
```

> - Rename OpenCVWrapper.m to “OpenCVWrapper.mm” for C++ support and add the following code:

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"

// import necessary headers
#import <opencv2/core.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+ (UIImage *) rgbImageFromBGRImage: (UIImage *) image {
    // Convert UIImage to cv::Mat
    Mat inputImage; UIImageToMat(image, inputImage);
    // If input image has only one channel, then return image.
    if (inputImage.channels() == 1) return image;
    // Convert the default OpenCV's BGR format to RGB.
    Mat outputImage; cvtColor(inputImage, outputImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
    // Convert the BGR OpenCV Mat to UIImage and return it.
    return MatToUIImage(outputImage);
}

@end
```

The minor difference from the linked article is they are converting BGR to grayscale but we are converting BGR to RGB (*good thing OpenCV has [tons of conversions](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html)!*).

### *Finally...*

Now that there is a bridging header to this Objective-C class you can use `OpenCVWrapper` in Swift:

```
// assume bgrImage is your image from the server
let rgbImage = OpenCVWrapper.rgbImage(fromBGR: bgrImage)
// double check the syntax on this ^ I'm not 100% sure how the bridging header will convert it
```

Comment: I posted a way to use `CoreImage` to do this. It *does* require iOS 9 as it uses a custom kernel. (If CoreImage itself was all that is needed it still would need iOS 8.) This was the very first kernel I ever wrote nearly two years ago and I just tested it. @Paolo, your way is intriguing! I've never (yet) used openCV. I'll look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the underlying CGImage to create a CIImage in the format you desire.

```
func changeToRGBA8(image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
  guard let cgImage = image.cgImage,
    let data = cgImage.dataProvider?.data else { return nil }
    let flipped = CIImage(bitmapData: data as Data,
                          bytesPerRow: cgImage.bytesPerRow,
                          size: CGSize(width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height),
                          format: kCIFormatRGBA8,
                          colorSpace: cgImage.colorSpace)
    return UIImage(ciImage: flipped)
}
```

The only issue is this only works if the `UIImage` was created with a `CGImage` in the first place! You can also convert it to a `CIImage` then a `CGImage` but the same applies, it only works if the `UIImage` was created from a `CIImage`.

There are ways around this limitation that I'll explore and post here if I have a better answer.