# Control black and white coloring using CIImage filter in swift

Tags: swift, filter, nsimage, ciimage

My code converts a colored NSImage into grayscale. It then converts the grayscale into pure black and white image. Is there a way to create a filter which can specify how to convert the gray pixels into black / white? For example - 
1. If pixel value > 100, turn it into black.
2. Else turn the pixel into white.

What filter settings can I use to achieve this?

Updated with CIKernel custom filter:

```
func applyCustomCIFilter( path: String )->NSImage{
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let origImage = CIImage(contentsOf: url)!

    // Convert image into grayscale
    let grayImage = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: origImage])?.outputImage
    print("convert into black and white")

    // custom filter to convert light gray to white and dark gray to black
    let replaceGrayKernel = CIColorKernel( source:
        "kernel vec4 replaceGrayWithBlackOrWhite(sampler grayImage) {" +
            "if( sample(grayImage, samplerCoord(grayImage)).rgb > 0.7  ){" +
            "return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);" +
            "}" +
            "else" +
            "{" +
            "return vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
            "}" +
        "}"
    )

    //Apply custom filter to grayscale image. 
    //ERROR: blackAndWhiteImage is nil causing runtime failure
    let blackAndWhiteImage = replaceGrayKernel?.apply(extent: (grayImage!.extent), arguments: [grayImage as Any])

    //Convert CIImage to NSImage
    let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: blackAndWhiteImage!)
    let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
    nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)

    return nsImage;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind, my experience is with iOS, not macOS. But I think this has to be the case with macOS also - if not today, after WWDC19. I believe there is no "canned" filter that will do this. But a very simple CIKL (`CIKernel`) should do the trick. Just be aware that RGB values are 0...1, not 0...255.

Comment: @dfd, Will give CIKernel a try. Or would you suggest doing this using bitmap image replacing the color for every pixel method? Sorry if this is a very basic question. I am new to Mac and Swift!

Comment: I can't "definitively" speak about using bitmapping, but I believe that route can only use the CPU. With CoreImage, you have several advantages, including using the GPU by default. I posted an example of swapping the red and blue pixels (using Swift 3, but no significant changes for Swift 5) that may help you. Instead of a simple return, you'll need to check for black, which is `vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968561/convert-uiimage-from-bgr-to-rgb/45969446#45969446

Comment: @dfd, I have updated my implementation using CIKernel. Looks like I am not creating the filter correctly. Any thoughts ? 

Basically, I want to create a filter to return WHITE if current pixel is light gray, else it should return a BLACK. Upon applying the custom filter, the resulting image is nil causing a runtime failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had 2 mistakes in your kernel code. Here's the correct code:

```
let kernel = CIColorKernel( source:
    "kernel vec4 replaceGrayWithBlackOrWhite(__sample s) {" +
        "if (s.r > 0.25 && s.g > 0.25 && s.b > 0.25) {" +
        "    return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);" +
        "} else {" +
        "    return vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);" +
        "}" +
    "}"
)
```

- The change from `sampler` to `__ sample` is because a `CIColorKernel`, which is optimized for working with one pixel at a time, just passes into the kernel that pixel. Thus, there's also no need for calling `sample(samplerCoord())`. `CIWarpKernel`, and `CIKernel` use `sampler`, as you send into the kernel a RIO (region of interest) and those kernels can access surrounding pixels... think blur effects.
- The second change was to the if statement. `if (s.rgb > 0.7)` is comparing a `vec3` (or three floats) to a single float. I had to play around with values once I corrected these and think that (a) using AND (`&&`) instead or OR (`||`) along with (b) lowering the threshold to 0.25 makes for a closer black/white image. Play around yourself with this to see what you want.

I've created a [small Swift 5 project](https://github.com/justdfd/BlackOrNot) (using a hard-coded image) that uses this kernel.

There's no comments in it and it contains various extensions (and a subclass of `GLKView`) because I gleaned things from a production project. Besides focusing on your kernel code issue, one word of warning about the code - it contains several force-unwraps that should be removed for "production-ready" code.

Comment: Really grateful for the help ! While I am still playing around with the values for my sample pictures, your code works beautifully on most.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up about force unwraps. Thats Xcode fixing my amateur swift code. Will be working on it very soon now that I have this figured out!