# Swift iOS: Core Image with Metal Kernel: Strange kernel behavior

Tags: ios, swift, metal, core-image, xcode13

Hello developer friends.

The first time I ask a question on Stackoverflow.

For the first time I came across writing custom Metal kernels to create a Core Image filter.

The task seemed simple. You need to make a filter to adjust the hue, saturation and lightness of colors in the image, limited by the hue range +/- 22.5 degrees. As in applications such as Lightroom color offset adjustment.

The algorithm is outrageously simple:

1. I pass the original pixel color and values for the range and offset of hue, saturation and lightness to the function;
2. Inside the function, I transform the color from the RGB scheme to the HSL scheme;
3. I check if the shade is in the target range;
   If I didn't hit it, I don't apply the offset, if I hit it, I add the offset values to the hue, saturation and lightness obtained during the conversion;
4. I will transform the pixel color back to the RGB scheme;
5. I return the result.

It turned out to be a wonderful algorithm that has been successfully and without any problems worked out in PlayGround:

Here is the source:

```
struct RGB {
    let r: Float
    let g: Float
    let b: Float
}

struct HSL {
    let hue: Float
    let sat: Float
    let lum: Float
}

func adjustingHSL(_ s: RGB, center: Float, hueOffset: Float, satOffset: Float, lumOffset: Float) -> RGB {
    // Determine the maximum and minimum color components
    let maxComp = (s.r > s.g && s.r > s.b) ? s.r : (s.g > s.b) ? s.g : s.b
    let minComp = (s.r < s.g && s.r < s.b) ? s.r : (s.g < s.b) ? s.g : s.b
    
    // Convert to HSL
    var inputHue: Float = (maxComp + minComp)/2
    var inputSat: Float = (maxComp + minComp)/2
    let inputLum: Float = (maxComp + minComp)/2
    
    if maxComp == minComp {
        inputHue = 0
        inputSat = 0
    } else {
        let delta: Float = maxComp - minComp
        
        inputSat = inputLum > 0.5 ? delta/(2.0 - maxComp - minComp) : delta/(maxComp + minComp)
        if (s.r > s.g && s.r > s.b) {inputHue = (s.g - s.b)/delta + (s.g < s.b ? 6.0 : 0.0) }
        else if (s.g > s.b) {inputHue = (s.b - s.r)/delta + 2.0}
        else {inputHue = (s.r - s.g)/delta + 4.0 }
        inputHue = inputHue/6
    }
    // Setting the boundaries of the offset hue range
    let minHue: Float = center - 22.5/(360)
    let maxHue: Float = center + 22.5/(360)
    
    // I apply offsets for hue, saturation and lightness 
    let adjustedHue: Float = inputHue + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? hueOffset : 0 )
    let adjustedSat: Float = inputSat + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? satOffset : 0 )
    let adjustedLum: Float = inputLum + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? lumOffset : 0 )
    
    // Convert color to RGB
    var red: Float = 0
    var green: Float = 0
    var blue: Float = 0
    
    if adjustedSat == 0 {
        red = adjustedLum
        green = adjustedLum
        blue = adjustedLum
    } else {
        let q = adjustedLum < 0.5 ? adjustedLum*(1+adjustedSat) : adjustedLum + adjustedSat - (adjustedLum*adjustedSat)
        let p = 2*adjustedLum - q
        
        var t: Float = 0
        // Calculating red
        t = adjustedHue + 1/3
        if t < 0 { t += 1 }
        if t > 1 { t -= 1 }
        
        if t < 1/6 { red = p + (q - p)*6*t }
        else if t < 1/2 { red = q }
        else if t < 2/3 { red = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6 }
        else { red = p }
        
        // Calculating green
        t = adjustedHue
        if t < 0 { t += 1 }
        if t > 1 { t -= 1 }
        
        if t < 1/6 { green = p + (q - p)*6*t }
        else if t < 1/2 { green = q }
        else if t < 2/3 { green = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6 }
        else { green = p }
        
        // Calculating blue
        t = adjustedHue - 1/3
        if t < 0 { t += 1 }
        if t > 1 { t -= 1 }
        
        if t < 1/6 { blue = p + (q - p)*6*t }
        else if t < 1/2 { blue = q }
        else if t < 2/3 { blue = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6 }
        else { blue = p }
        
    }
    
    return RGB(r: red, g: green, b: blue)
}
```

Application in the PlayGround for example like this:

```
let inputColor = RGB(r: 255/255, g: 120/255, b: 0/255)
   
 // For visual perception of the input color
let initColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(inputColor.r), green: CGFloat(inputColor.g), blue: CGFloat(inputColor.b), alpha: 1.0)

let rgb = adjustingHSL(inputColor, center: 45/360, hueOffset: 0, satOffset: 0, lumOffset: -0.2)

// For visual perception of the output color
let adjustedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(rgb.r), green: CGFloat(rgb.g), blue: CGFloat(rgb.b), alpha: 1.0)
```

The same function, rewritten for the Metal kernel in the Xcode project, gives a completely unexpected result.

The image after it becomes black and white. At the same time, changing the input parameters by sliders also changes the image itself. Only it is also strange: it is covered with small black or white squares.

Here is the source code in Metal kernel:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" {
    namespace coreimage {
        
        float4 hslFilterKernel(sample_t s, float center, float hueOffset, float satOffset, float lumOffset) {
            // Convert pixel color from RGB to HSL
            // Determine the maximum and minimum color components
            float maxComp = (s.r > s.g && s.r > s.b) ? s.r : (s.g > s.b) ? s.g : s.b ;
            float minComp = (s.r < s.g && s.r < s.b) ? s.r : (s.g < s.b) ? s.g : s.b ;
            
            float inputHue = (maxComp + minComp)/2 ;
            float inputSat = (maxComp + minComp)/2 ;
            float inputLum = (maxComp + minComp)/2 ;
            
            if (maxComp == minComp) {
                
                inputHue = 0 ;
                inputSat = 0 ;
            } else {
                float delta = maxComp - minComp ;
                
                inputSat = inputLum > 0.5 ? delta/(2.0 - maxComp - minComp) : delta/(maxComp + minComp);
                
                if (s.r > s.g && s.r > s.b) {
                    inputHue = (s.g - s.b)/delta + (s.g < s.b ? 6.0 : 0.0);
                } else if (s.g > s.b) {
                    inputHue = (s.b - s.r)/delta + 2.0;
                }
                else {
                    inputHue = (s.r - s.g)/delta + 4.0;
                }
                inputHue = inputHue/6 ;
            }
            
            float minHue = center - 22.5/(360) ;
            float maxHue = center + 22.5/(360) ;

            //I apply offsets for hue, saturation and lightness 
            
            float adjustedHue = inputHue + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? hueOffset : 0 );
            float adjustedSat = inputSat + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? satOffset : 0 );
            float adjustedLum = inputLum + ((inputHue > minHue && inputHue < maxHue) ? lumOffset : 0 );
            
            // Convert pixel color from HSL to RGB
            
            float red = 0 ;
            float green = 0 ;
            float blue = 0 ;
            
            if (adjustedSat == 0) {
                red = adjustedLum;
                green = adjustedLum;
                blue = adjustedLum;
            } else {
                
                float q = adjustedLum < 0.5 ? adjustedLum*(1+adjustedSat) : adjustedLum + adjustedSat - (adjustedLum*adjustedSat);
                float p = 2*adjustedLum - q;
                
                // Calculating Red color
                float t = adjustedHue + 1/3;
                if (t < 0) { t += 1; }
                if (t > 1) { t -= 1; }
                
                if (t < 1/6) { red = p + (q - p)*6*t; }
                else if (t < 1/2) { red = q; }
                else if (t < 2/3) { red = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6; }
                else { red = p; }
                
                // Calculating Green color
                t = adjustedHue;
                if (t < 0) { t += 1; }
                if (t > 1) { t -= 1; }
                
                if (t < 1/6) { green = p + (q - p)*6*t; }
                else if (t < 1/2) { green = q ;}
                else if (t < 2/3) { green = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6; }
                else { green = p; }
                
                // Calculating Blue color
                
                t = adjustedHue - 1/3;
                if (t < 0) { t += 1; }
                if (t > 1) { t -= 1; }
                
                if (t < 1/6) { blue = p + (q - p)*6*t; }
                else if (t < 1/2) { blue = q; }
                else if (t < 2/3) { blue = p + (q - p)*(2/3 - t)*6;}
                else { blue = p; }
                
            }

            float4 outColor;
            outColor.r = red;
            outColor.g = green;
            outColor.b = blue;
            outColor.a = s.a;
            
            return outColor;
            
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where I could have made a mistake.

Just in case, I attach a filter class (but it seems to work fine):

```
class HSLAdjustFilter: CIFilter {
    
    var inputImage: CIImage?
    var center: CGFloat?
    var hueOffset: CGFloat?
    var satOffset: CGFloat?
    var lumOffset: CGFloat?
   
    static var kernel: CIKernel = { () -> CIColorKernel in
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "HSLAdjustKernel.ci", withExtension: "metallib"),
              let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        else { fatalError("Unable to load metallib") }
        
        guard let kernel = try? CIColorKernel(functionName: "hslFilterKernel", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        else { fatalError("Unable to create color kernel") }
        
        return kernel
    }()
    
    
    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else { return nil }
  
        return HSLAdjustFilter.kernel.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, roiCallback: { _, rect in return rect }, arguments: [inputImage, self.center ?? 0, self.hueOffset ?? 0, self.satOffset ?? 0, self.lumOffset ?? 0])
    }
    
}
```

Also the function of calling the filter:

```
func imageProcessing(_ inputImage: CIImage) -> CIImage {

        let filter = HSLAdjustFilter()
        
        filter.inputImage = inputImage
        filter.center = 180/360
        filter.hueOffset = CGFloat(hue)
        filter.satOffset = CGFloat(saturation)
        filter.lumOffset = CGFloat(luminance)
        
        if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
            return outputImage
        } else {
            return inputImage
        }
    }
```

The most depressing thing is that you can't even output anything to the console. It is unclear how to look for errors.
I will be grateful for any hints.

PS: **Xcode 13.1**, **iOS 14-15**. SwiftUI life cycle.

GitHub: https://github.com/VKostin8311/MetalKernelsTestApp

Comment: Nice question - and upvoted. My experience is (for now) mostly with OpenGL kernels and UIKit. I noticed two things in your question. First, the last three words "SwiftUI life cycle". Do you think this is the reason, or is it actually simply "noise" to the actual issue? Second, since this is a color kernel, try some things. Here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968561/convert-uiimage-from-bgr-to-rgb/45969446#45969446 it might eliminate playgrounds, UIKit, and point you to what's going on.

Comment: The life cycle of SwiftUI does not interfere here. I tried to temporarily remove all the code from the Metal Kernel and just returned the input color. As a result, everything is fine with the image. I also tried to swap the input colors. Here, too, an adequate result is quite expected. Finally, I tried to return colors using input offsets. Also quite expected behavior. The big problem is finding bugs. Where I can at least call the print() function and see the process in the console. Breakpoints are also not triggered. Source code on Github: https://github.com/VKostin8311/MetalKernelsTestApp

Answer (score 4):

Welcome!

The main issue with the kernel code is the use of integer literals:

The Metal Shading Language is based on C++, which doesn't have the same type inference system as Swift. So when you write `1/3` it will actually perform integer division, so that something like `float t = adjustedHue + 1/3` would equal `adjustedHue + 0`. You have to use float literals here: `adjustedHue + 1.0/3.0`.

I created a pull request on your sample project with various fixes and improvements. Please let me know if something is unclear.

As for debugging: Debugging kernel code is unfortunately not possible with breakpoints and direct print statements. I usually use pixel colors for `printf`-debugging like this:

```
if (<condition I want to check>) { return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); }
```

All pixels that meet the condition become red in this case, which you can use to verify assumptions, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The image looks much better. We just need to look again. Rectangles of different colors appear in some photos, mostly black or white. Perhaps because of the not very good quality of photographic materials

Comment: Glad I could help. Do you maybe have a reference implementation for the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: There is only an implementation for the CPU on Swift. And it is also being debugged in terms of performance and ranges. The goal is to surpass the Lightroom.