# Inverted Colours when Writing an Image using TensorFlow and PIL

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save images with bounding boxes displayed on them, just to test that my annotations file is working correctly.

Everything works out fine: the image is written to disk, the bounding box is there in the right place and so on. Except all the colours are inverted. So it looks like a negative of the original image.

Here is my code:

```

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def read_processed_data(filename, num_show):
    """ Reads in the processed data file and displays the
        given number of images, along with the bounding boxes.
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        i = 0

        while i < num_show:
            for line in f:
                filename = line.rstrip()
                next_line = f.readline()
                num_faces = int(next_line.rstrip())
                face_num = 0

                #while face_num < num_faces:
                bb_line = f.readline().rstrip()
                y1, x1, y2, x2 = bb_line.split(',')
                y1 = float(y1)
                x1 = float(x1)
                y2 = float(y2)
                x2 = float(x2)

                box = [y1, x1, y2, x2]

                return box, filename


with tf.Session() as sess:
    bb, fn = read_processed_data("processed.txt", 1)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(fn))

    image_as_float = tf.cast(image, dtype = tf.float32)
    image_4d = tf.expand_dims(image_as_float, 0)

    bb_2d = tf.expand_dims(bb, 0)
    bb_3d = tf.expand_dims(bb_2d, 0) # Box has to be 3d for the drawing to work
    bb_image = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(image_4d, bb_3d)
    bb_image_uint = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(bb_image, dtype = tf.uint8)
    bb_image_uint_3d = tf.reshape(bb_image_uint, [940, 650, 3]) # Reduce rank from 4 to 3
    data = bb_image_uint_3d.eval()

    base_fn = fn.split('.')[0]
    Image.fromarray(data).save(base_fn + "_bb.jpg")
```

```

I have searched the tensorflow documentation to no avail. I have also attempted `np.roll()` and the other suggestions from [PIL rotate image colors (BGR -> RGB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661557/pil-rotate-image-colors-bgr-rgb) again with no luck; those methods were able to change the colour, but not to the correct colours.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N23ia.jpg shows the original image (without bounding box) at the top, and the resulting image (with the colour issue, as well as bounding box) below.

Comment: May not be the cause, but I'd suggest to add `saturate=True` when calling `convert_image_dtype` to avoid overflow errors.

Comment: you posted this literally just as I was trying `saturate_cast()`, which works! I'll post the full code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `saturate_cast()`. It appears that the uint8 --> float32 or float32 --> uint8 conversion (I suspect the latter) led to an overflow.

The fixed section of code is

```
image_as_float = tf.saturate_cast(image, dtype = tf.float32)
image_4d = tf.expand_dims(image_as_float, 0)    # Add in a batch dimension (of size 1)

bb_2d = tf.expand_dims(bb, 0)   # Add in dimension of size 1 (num_bounding_boxes)
bb_3d = tf.expand_dims(bb_2d, 0)    # Add in dimension of size 1 (batch)
bb_image = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(image_4d, bb_3d)
bb_image_uint = tf.saturate_cast(bb_image, dtype = tf.uint8)
```

Thanks to [de1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8676953/de1) for the suggestion, which came just as I was testing the fixed code.