# Why RGB value is different when getpixel in PIL and when use Eyedropper tool in Photoshop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, photoshop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEqyK.jpg)
When I get RGB of (2835, 5089) in Photoshop, I get (112, 213, 240)
But I did the same thing in PIL, I get (5, 186, 241)
Why are they different?

I try to remove some words.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("SCN_0010.jpg")
for i in range(0, img.size[0]):
    for j in range(0, img.size[1]):
        r, g, b = img.getpixel((i, j))
        if r > 40:
            break
        if g < 150 or g > 200:
            break
        if b < 210:
            break
        img.putpixel((i, j), (0, 0, 0))
img.save("edited/SCN_0010.jpg")
```

But the RGB values were different so I can't do it.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("SCN_0010.jpg")
print(img.getpixel((2835, 5089)))
```

This is the code when I feel strange and do some test.

Comment: Just wondering: what are the RGB values of (5089, 2835) in PIL, and are those maybe the same as (2835, 5089) in Photoshop?

Comment: I have encountered this problem myself (in fact i believe that i wrote about this in my book). It is because PIL is BGR and not RGB. Here is a conversion:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661557/pil-rotate-image-colors-bgr-rgb

Comment: It's weird. because I just tested and neither the sizes was swapped nor the color standards (RGB , BGR). It returned the right value

Comment: Photoshop is colour-managed and respects ICC colour profiles and transforms images to its concept of a *"working profile"*. **PIL** doesn't work like that.

Comment: Not sure how you are accessing pixel at (2835,5089) in an image which is 3274x4630?

Comment: This is a side point - but the image you show is only 3247 x 4630 pixels so whatever pixel you are trying to grab at 2835, 5089 is out of range. Secondly, that image is quite pixelated (moire patterns) and the colour is not flat and constant. Which may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: um.. I don't know why the image change to 3247 x 4630 pixels. but it's original one is 4960 x 7015

Comment: @GhoulFool Could you tell me more about the sceond part? I can't understand and it doesn't have much information on Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, more of a comment with images, but explains some of the problems encountered.

Your source image is probably from a scan. Whilst initially it looks okay... but if we take a closer look there are no large areas of flat colour.
[image: Source image zoomed in]

However, the original image will be clean; something like this:

[image: clean image]

This is a Moiré pattern. You can learn more about them [here](https://www.scantips.com/basics06.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

So what's this got to do with anything??

If we look at the clean image, the green is RGB 181, 205, 49.
Whereas, if we look at an 8x8 pixel sample there are 58 shades of green there:

[image: 8x8 image]

111,138,0
114,141,0
115,140,0
121,148,0
122,149,0
123,149,0
123,150,0
127,154,0
130,155,0
131,157,4
132,159,4
134,159,5
134,161,4
135,162,7
136,163,8
138,165,8
139,166,11
141,168,11
143,168,14
143,170,13
144,171,16
154,180,27
156,183,28
160,186,33
162,187,33
163,188,34
164,191,36
165,192,37
166,191,35
167,194,39
168,194,41
170,195,41
170,196,43
170,197,42
171,198,43
172,199,44
175,202,45
177,203,50
177,204,47
177,204,49
178,205,48
178,205,50
182,205,62
182,209,54
185,210,57
185,212,55
189,216,61
193,220,65
196,221,67
202,229,72
202,229,74
203,228,72
204,231,76
206,231,77
208,233,80
212,239,84
229,255,99
238,255,108

In short:
You might want to a test with images that use flat colour and then work out why the RGB values are different rather than having the added complications of further colour variations.